# How to find documents according to a common field value from another collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

Assume I have 2 collections:
student:

```
{name: Joe, school: A}
{name: Kelly, school: B}
{name: Mike, school: C}
{name: Tom, school: D}
```

schoolRank: (all the school rank is stored in one document)

```
{rank: [{school: A, value: 1},{school: B, value: 2},{school: C, value: 3},{school: D, value: 4}]}
```

Now, **my question is how could I find the student whoes school rank is higher than 3**. (I am a newbie to mongodb. It seems like I need to use lookup but I am not sure how to do it exactly.) Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/). Is like a "join" in SQL.

But, first of all. Your document could be much better. `schoolRank` collection could have every school in a document instead of a unique array wit all values.

Check here the difference between the query with [your schema](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QoVx1DqSio8) and the schema with `schoolRank` splited into [diffretend documents](https://mongoplayground.net/p/05yA0xILvlP).

The second query return only the document where field `school` match. The other will return the entire array for each document, because in each document exist a field `school` that also exists into `rank` array.

So, with your schema you need extra stages. Maybe there is another way more efficent, but I'm not used to do `$lookup` with a bad schema (sorry).

I've try this query:

First `$lookup` to join both collections (as I've said before, the join is basically add the entire array into each document).

Then an extra stage to get the value returned from `$lookup` using `$set` with the element at first position.

After that, using `$project` te query can filter the field `rank_school` and overwrite it to get only the element which field `school` is the same as `student.school`.

> Note that the above steps could be omitted using another schema.

Then, after the `$project` there is a `$match` stage to get the documents whose `rank_school.value` is greater or equal than 3.

And the last stage is another `$project` to remove the field `rank_school`.

This is the query:

```js
db.student.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "schoolRank",
      "localField": "school",
      "foreignField": "rank.school",
      "as": "rank_school"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": { "rank_school": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$rank_school", 0 ] } }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "name": "$name",
      "school": "$school",
      "rank_school": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$rank_school.rank",
          "as": "rank_school_filter",
          "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$rank_school_filter.school", "$school" ] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": { "rank_school.value": { "$gte": 3 } }
  },
  {
    "$project": { "rank_school": 0 }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LHzT0akwSYX).

And the output is:

```json
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000003"),
    "name": "Mike",
    "school": "C"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000004"),
    "name": "Tom",
    "school": "D"
  }
]
```

Comment: You are welcome! Also if the issue has been resolverd, mark the answer as accept is apreciated.

Comment: Hi J.F. can you please help me with this question , I am stuck. I will be very grateful for your help. Thank you **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68192868/mongo-query-to-fetch-documents-on-the-basis-of-same-field-value-and-those-which?noredirect=1#comment120523178_68192868**